# Why does accessing GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes by key throw an exception even when ContainsKey returns true?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

---

I have the following code that works on my development machine but fails in a UAT environment with the "given key not found in dictionary" exception.

```
if (GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.ContainsKey(routeName))
     return GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes[routeName];
```

Also, interesting is that in the UAT environment the `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.Count` returns 19 but `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes[0]` also throws an exception.  All routing seems to work fine otherwise. I've double-checked that the web.configs are the same except for db configs.  I would love any hint at where to even start debugging this.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by threading issue.

Comment: Not sure if dynamically routes updating is allowed (not very familiar with webapi). But is it possible that route table is changed after the `ContainsKey` check?